# javascript : cannot intercept key combination for Ctrl + Shift + key in chrome : is it non maskable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to intercept all Ctrl + Shift + a key sequence in chrome ?
Especially Ctrl + Shift + "n" ?

```
        $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (e.ctrlKey) // ok
                console.log('ctrl');
            if (e.shiftKey) // ok
                console.log('shift');
            if (e.key === "n") // ok 
                debugger;
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey) // ok
                debugger;
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === "n") {
                debugger; // nope never reaches this. always open a new window instead
            }
        })
```

Comment: I don't think a random website should be able to change what default shortcuts in a browser do. And it seems Chrome agrees. Ctrl-Shift-N opens a new incognito window for me, why should a website be allowed to change that?

Comment: Because it makes more sense in the context of this website : it's a windows explorer lookalike and ctrl+shift+n create new dir in windows explorer

Comment: sorry, but my need not to get my browser hijacked by malicious websites changing how it reacts to default shortcuts overrides your need to emulate Windows Explorer inside a browser window.

Comment: I just test in FF and it works (but FF doesn't map anything to ctrl + shift + n). Too bad there's no policy to allow this in Chrome.

Comment: you might get somewhere by turning your thing into a chrome app, but those are being sunset right now, so it's not a horse I'd start betting on now.

Comment: It might make sense for your single website, but it does not make sense for a browser that serve billions of websites per day to allow 1 potentially malicious script to ruin the whole user experience and security of that browser.

Comment: Compared to what ?  I could make this a web application but I don't think it'll resolve my problem. I could go for a chrome application but I'd prefer not to. An electron app would be a waste of ressources. I'd probably just map to another shortcut. But it's pita users can't just use the shortcuts they already know.

Comment: @Yong Quan. It could make sense for every "website/application" that replicates existing desktop application which shortcuts users are accustomed to.